# Table partitioning on years and months

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Partitioning SQL Server table on years and months

I was wondering if it is possible to partition a SQL Server table's datetime column on both Year and Month.

For example, the data related to records in 2018 and 2019 should reside in 2 different filegroups.

After this, is it possible that data can be further partitioned into months for each year? For example, the filegroup for Year 2018 should have 1 partition for 2018 and then 12 more partitions for every month? Same goes for other years like 2019, 2020 and so on.

Sorry if the questions seems a bit vague, but I'm trying to get my head around this and can't find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can specify a different file group for every individual partition, so you can simply partition by absolute month (year + month) and direct all the partitions from one year to one file group.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I'll need a partition function and partition scheme for every year, and all the months in 2018 for example should be directed to one filegroup in partition scheme, same goes for 2019 and so forth ?

Comment: No, you need only one partition function and one scheme. You can partition on two columns (year + month) if they're separate or just on a single date column if they're not and then direct each partition to a yearly file group as necessary. If you partitioned by year, you could only have one partition per year, not by month. I.e. `CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf(datetime) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2005-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2005-02-01T00:00:00.000', N'2005-03-01T00:00:00.000', ...`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for monthly partitioning. Now trying to do portioning by quarter, for some reason it's still placing every month in different partition rather than months in a quarter in a single partition, will try more on this but any suggestion would be appreciated.